# Tell-Don't-Ask principle for finding distance within same class

Tags: java, oop

From what I understand of the Tell-Don't-Ask principle, my other classes should not be able to call upon the data stored in any other class. Hence, getters are frowned upon under this principle. In order to prevent access into the data, they are normally written as:

```
class Point {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;
}
```

However, if I were to implement methods like distance between 2 points, I would need to access the x and y of the other point. In this case, I would need the getter method.

```
class Point {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    private double getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    private double getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public double distanceBetween(Point p) {
        double dx = this.x - p.getX();
        double dy = this.y - p.getY();
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
}
```

Wouldn't this violate the Tell-Don't-Ask principle? As now, I opened the data within the class to be accessed? Or is my understanding of the Tell-Don't-Ask principle wrong?

Comment: Are you talking about the `Tell, Don't Ask` principle? I don't see anything online about a Show, Don't Ask principle.

Comment: You don't need getters for your example above. The `Point` class can access all its members so `this.x - p.x` would also work. That being said, it would be news to me that getters are frowned upon in java code. As long as those getter aren't for an internal field that doesn't need to be exposed to the outside. But being able to get a points x and y coordinates even outside of the class doesn't seem purposeless to me.

Comment: I am sorry, I was indeed referring to Tell-Don't-Ask. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are "allowed" to access the data stored in yourself as a `Point`. So a `Point` object can access data stored inside itself, but also in other `Point` objects.

In short, that does *not* violate Tell-don't-ask (I assume that is what you mean).

Also, you don't need a getter method. Fields marked "private" can be accessed from any method in the class, regardless of instances of that class. The reason for that is exactly the above.